# How to make this script run faster?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hello so I am trying to get values from the 'book' sheet then copy it to 'Completed' sheet. It takes the values form book stores it in the data array and copy them to the 'Completed' sheet. Its working fine but very slow which jeopardizes my work in time-wise. How can I make this run faster ?

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var clear_sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Completed_Orders'); // clear the destination sheet first
  clear_sheet.getRange('A2:X').clear();


  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('book'); //source sheet
  var Datarange = sheet.getRange('Q3:Q'); //range to check
  var Datavalue = (Datarange.getValues());
  var dest = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Completed_Orders'); //destination sheet
  var data = [];
  for (i=0; i<Datavalue.length;i++) {
    if ( Datavalue[i] == "Completed") {
      data.push.apply(data,sheet.getRange(i+3,1,1,24).getValues());
    }
  }
  dest.getRange(2,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);

  var column = dest.getRange('A3:A');
  var values = column.getValues(); // get all data in one call
  var ct = 0;
  while ( values[ct][0] != "" ) { // to find the last row correctly, getLastRow is not working perfectly
    ct++;
  }
  var endRow = ct+2;
}
```

Comment: Your question can be improved by providing your work so far in trying to optimize the script.  Specifically explain whether "best practices" in the documentation were followed and  provide the slowest block  in your code using `console.time`. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: Can you share a spreadsheet with Dummy Data? Also, please check [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Don't use this syntax `var values=sheet.getRange('A3:A').getValues()` because it get's the data all the way down to getMaxRows().  Instead use `var values=sheet.getRange(3,1,sheet.getLastRow()-2,1).getValues()`.

Also Datavalue[i] is a whole row

```
function myfunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var clear_sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Completed_Orders'); 
  clear_sheet.getRange(2,1,clear_sheet.getLastRow()-1,24).clear();    
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('book'); //source sheet
  var Datarange = sheet.getRange(3,17,sheet.getLastRow()-2,1); //range to check
  var Datavalue = Datarange.getValues();
  var dest = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Completed_Orders'); //destination sheet
  var data = [];
  for (var i=0;i<Datavalue.length;i++) {
    if (Datavalue[i]["************You need another index here**************"] == "Completed") { //need another index Datavalue is 2d
      data.push(sheet.getRange(i+3,1,1,24).getValues());
    }
  }
  dest.getRange(2,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

I think this version will be a lot faster.

```
function myfunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssh=ss.getSheetByName('book');
  var dsh=ss.getSheetByName('Completed_Orders'); 
  dsh.getRange(2,1,dsh.getLastRow()-1,24).clear();    
  var dv=ssh.getRange(3,1,ssh.getLastRow()-2,24).getValues();//this version just gets this data one time so it should a lot faster.
  var data=[];
  for (var i=0;i<dv.length;i++) {
    if (dv[i][16]=="Completed") { 
      data.push(dv[i]);
    }
  }
  dsh.getRange(2,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: I have made the changes but still running slowly. Also if its taking long than 6 minutes, the script is stopped automatically.

Comment: As I looked closer I realized that your getting a complete rows for every line of the spreadsheet in the loop.  So the best thing is just to get all of the data at one time and compare column `17` to `Completed` and only include completed rows into `oA`.  This should run a lot faster